# Causal inference for continuous exposures

Tags: panel-data, causality, propensity-scores, dag

I am new to causal inference world and want to find which is the correct statistical procedure that can be applied to my data.
I found a number of predictors <sup>1...n</sup> which are associated with a continuous outcome  in a cross-sectional setting (N<sub>samples</sub>~1000), both the predictors and the outcome being age-dependent and associated with some confounders (e.g., sex).
For a subset of this sample (N<sub>samples</sub>~250), I have both variables measured at two time-points (in average 5 years apart), and I want to identify predictors showing evidence for causal relationship.
I am wondering what is the best way to tackle this problem.
I came across the propensity score methods but, as far as I know, these methods have been mostly used for binary exposure variables.
Thanks

Comment: Are you interested in evaluating the causal effect of a single variable, or trying to discover which variables cause the outcome? Those are two different questions and only the former can be answered using propensity score methods. The latter may not be answerable at all. If you're just looking for associations, then a regular regression would work, but it will provide you with little useful information (i.e., it will tell you nothing about intervening on one of the variables).

Comment: If you want to evaluate the causal relationship between a predictor $X$ and the outcome $Y$, you could consider estimating the function $x \mapsto E_W[Y|X=x,W]$ where $W$ are the remaining features. This would under causal assumptions identify the causal effect of $X$ on $Y$ accounting for $W$. Even without these assumptions, it is still a useful parameter to assess association. You could plot $E_W[Y|X=x,W]$ against $x$ to get an idea for the strength of the relationship (or estimate the average slope).

Comment: Search for the "causal dose-response curve" or "conditional average treatment effect". Some papers that come to mind are causal isotonic regression, Westling, Carone, 2020 and a paper by Edward Kennedy. I am not sure whether there are easy to access implementations but the methods are described in the papers. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.00747.pdf, https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.03269

Comment: You could also utilize binary exposure packages and discretize your continuous variable (e.g. define $A_x:= 1(X \geq x)$ and estimate $E_WE[Y|A_x=1,W]$ for a range of $x$ values. This would also give a curve that assesses the association of $X$ with $Y$. You could use the R package "tmle" for example. I also have a github R package that estimates and provides inference for $E_WE[Y|X\geq x,W]$. If this interests you, you can message me.

Comment: My first comment was badly written. I meant to write $x \mapsto E_W E[Y|X=x,W]$ which under some assumptions (e.g. $W$ includes all confounders among others) would identify the average outcome obtained by the intervention setting $X=x$. Without causal assumptions, which are probably not true anyway if you are doing this for all your features, this function measures the association between $X$ and $Y$ adjusting for $W$, which is still an interesting variable importance "measure" of $X$.

Comment: thanks for all your suggestions. I like the idea of discretizing the exposure for a range of values. I'll give "tmle" a try, as it can account for repeated measures!